# Как найти словарь с минимальным значением в python?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть несколько словарей:

```
d1 = {v: 1}
d2 = {v: 2}
d3 = {v: 3}
```

как найти словарь с минимальным значением v?

Comment: `min([d1, d2, d3], key=lambda x: x['v'])` ?

Comment: @insolor изящно.. а я пошёл циклом, да ещё и через список.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как отметил товарищ [@insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor), можно воспользоваться опциональным аргументом `key` функции `min(list, key)`, с помощью которого будут проверяться ключи в словаре:

```
min([d1, d2, d3], key=lambda x: x['v'])
```